# Webdriver: browser dimensions are never changed under jenkins

Tags: firefox, selenium, jenkins

So I'm running Jenkins as a windows service on my local machine (which has a monitor attached, system screen resolution is 1600x900) and some selenium wd (2.44.0) based tests on firefox (from 25 to 31)

So, whenever I run tests with remote driver (in this case firefox is rendered at my desktop), using `maximize()` or `setSize(Dimension)` on `driver.window()` will have effect - browser window will be resized.

If tests are run under jenkins user (thus, driver is not rendered at my desktop), maximum firefox window resolution is **1028** x smth, which seems strange according to screenshots.

1. Tried both `setSize` and `maximize`
2. Tried Different FF versions, 25, 29, 31

How can I force window resize in such case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Service running is limited to resolution and changed somehow from the registry (not sure for now without googling), the thing that maximum reolution for tipical programes is not the same as for services.

The solution that could be provided is not to run it as a service, but stop the service and as "java -jar jenkins.war".